# FLVPlayback Event.Complete not detecting video ending

Tags: actionscript-3, flvplayback

I'm using Flash CC 2015 and Action Script 3.0. The general idea is a menu (that's on frame 1), with buttons that lead to frames with different FLVPlayback components that play videos. Upon completion of the video I want to return to the menu on frame 1.

Here's what I have an frame 2 (where the component is) so far:

```
import fl.video.*;

stop();

var hole1:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();
hole1.source = "Hole 1.mp4"

hole1.width = 1920;
hole1.height= 1200;
hole1.scaleMode = VideoScaleMode.MAINTAIN_ASPECT_RATIO;


addChild(hole1);

hole1Vid.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, playbackComplete);

function playbackComplete(event:Event):void
{
    trace("Video End");
    gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

The main menu links to this frame and plays without any issue, however nothing happens when the video ends.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: The `Event.COMPLETE` is not attached to your `hole1` `FLVPlayback` component but to `hole1Vid` !

Comment: You added the event listener to hole1Vid. What is hole1Vid? Maybe change that to hole1